# GWT - CellList wont update when underlying list changes

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, celllist

I have 2 ArrayLists that I want to display at alternate times. I have a button that when clicked should swap out the first list for the second list.

I have tried 2 approaches with little success.

The first approach was to create a ListDataProvider and bind it to the list and table, but when the button was clicked and the list structure changed nothing happened./

My second approach was to stick with the normal CellList and simply reset the row count and row data. This approach works if I click my button twice.

What could i be overlooking? Any help will be much appreciated!

Code is as follows:

This is when I try re add the ArrayList to the CellList

```
public void refreshTable()
{
    systemTable.setRowCount(SYSTEMS.size(), true);
    systemTable.setRowData(0, SYSTEMS);
}
```

I tried it with the ListDataProvider as follows:

```
 private ListDataProvider<String> listDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>(SYSTEMS);

public void refreshTable()
{
    listDataProvider.refresh();
}
```

Comment: Added code to try explain what I was saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably running into this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7114).

Both versions should work. 
For the first solution try to reverse the calls (call first `setRowData()` and then `setRowCount()`):

```
public void refreshTable()
{
    systemTable.setRowData(0, SYSTEMS);
    systemTable.setRowCount(SYSTEMS.size(), true);
}
```

for the second solution I think you forgot to call `addDataDisplay`. 
Here are some ways to change the underlying data:

1.) create a new ListDataProvider and set the `DataDisplay` (you don't need to call refresh):

```
private ListDataProvider<String> listDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>(SYSTEMS);
listDataProvider.addDataDisplay(systemTable);
```

2.) set a new list of the existing ListDataProvider:

```
   listDataProvider.setList(SYSTEMS);
```

3.) modify the existing list:

```
   listDataProvider.getList().add/remove etc
```